# How to add a ℃ in org-mode which can be correctly exported to latex

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, emacs24

I tried sometimes and realized that exporter can recognize $1100^{\circ}C$ and 1000^\circ, but can not recognize 1000^\circC and 1000^\circ C correctly, so which is the best way to add a ℃? I would not like to use $1100^{\circ}C$, because it need to add two whitespaces in both sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use an appropriate wysiwyg character here.

A sample org file:

```
Foo! The temp is 12 °C.
```

The PDF after `C-x C-e l o`:

[image: pdf preview]

Different extended alphabet symbols can be typed with Emacs' `C-x 8` subbindings. For instance:

```
Key            Gives
---------------------
C-x 8 o         °
C-x 8 u         µ
```

Be sure to check `C-x 8 C-h` for some of the mapped symbols.

Check also the input method `TeX`. It is pretty cool. It translates directly written TeX macros into unicode symbols. `C-\ TeX RET` and you're set.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. But can you tell me how to input these wysiwyg characters?

Comment: @user3173715: if you use Evil, then you can do the degree in insert mode with `C-k DG`. If not, there should be something under `C-x 8` but I haven't really used that feature.

Comment: I found a solution. Thank you anyway. And can you suggest me something about the input of micrometer unit in org-mode?

Comment: @user3173715: out of sheer luck, the first key turned out to be correct: `C-x 8 u` provides the letter µ. BTW, `C-x 8 o` gives °.

Answer (score 0):

If i would insert a Celsius symbol with C-x 8 o , it still would convert it to a non printable or useless character. The only way the Celsius sign works for me is when i insert it in org-mode with \textdegree

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to replace the symbol with some latex command. I would recommend the siunitx package which I think yields better results in general. For example, with the code below and \usepackage{siunitx} in the header, you could write 12 °C in the Org document and it becomes \SI{12}{\degreeCelsius} in the tex file.

```
(defun org-latex-replace-degree (text backend info)
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
    (replace-regexp-in-string
     "\\([0-9\.]*\\)\s?\\(°C\\)" "\\\\SI\{\\1\}\{\\\\degreeCelsius\}" text)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-plain-text-functions 'org-latex-replace-degree)
```